# Need to import .dmp file into Oracle Express, export it as a flat CSV or TXT file for importation into SAS

Tags: oracle, csv, text, sas, dmp

Does anyone know how to write a specific command line that imports a .dmp file into an Oracle Express database, and then exports the data as a CSV file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ - find the imp executable and use it interactively to import your data.

Comment: I was wondering whether you had any luck with this (I have a similar problem) and whether you could share your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, thus far, no luck. I am dealing with a mid-90s Orahome server; I can't seem to work with the extracted .dmp files, nor successfully spool out the data. I think we are going to try to find a TOAD version that works and install it on the Oracle computer and work from there; I have been told that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import using impdp:

```
impdp scott/tiger@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=impdpEMP_DEPT.log
```

Then spool to csv:

```
set heading off
spool myfile.csv
select col1|','||col2 from my_tables;
set colsep ','
select * from my_table;
spool off;
```

Follow below links for help.

> import: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g
>   spool to csv: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_export_to_csv_file.htm

Comment: Thank you for this information- I have several questions: 1) is the "scott/tiger@db10g" string a username/password@databasename, or is it the username/password of the developer?  Also, can one change the "test_dir" where the .dmp file to a location on the locale PC? I am having trouble getting this to work; fairly new to Oracle. Any help very appreciated!

Comment: 1. username/password@databasename 2. yes you can change directory. for that you nee to create a new directory in db then you have give permission to the user you want to use for expdp or impdp. then you can change directory. but before that make it sure that the os user has permission on that directory.